# Can any poset of cardinality $\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$ be embedded in ${\cal P}(\omega)/(\text{fin})$?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, lattice-theory, posets, boolean-algebras

We endow ${\cal P}(\omega)$ with an equivalence relation by saying that $A\simeq_{\text{fin}} B$ iff the symmetric difference $A\Delta B$ is finite. The resulting set of equivalence classes is denoted ${\cal P}(\omega)/(\text{fin})$, and by $$[A]_{\simeq_{\text{fin}}} \leq [B]_{\simeq_{\text{fin}}} \text{ if and only if } A\setminus B \text{ is finite } $$ for $A,B\in {\cal P}(\omega)$, we get a partial order on ${\cal P}(\omega)/(\text{fin})$, resulting in an atomless Boolean algebra.

Can any poset $(P,\leq)$ with $|P|\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$ be order-embedded into ${\cal P}(\omega)/(\text{fin})$?

Comment: This is true if $\mathsf{CH}$ holds; I suspect it's independent in general, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @NoahSchweber's suspicion is correct. A negative answer is consistent with  ZFC. In fact, the  unembeddable poset $P$ can be just the ordinal $\mathfrak c$. This was proved by Peter Dordal in "A model in which the base matrix tree cannot have cofinal branches" (Journal of Symbolic Logic 52 (1987) pp. 651--664).

Comment: And Ken Kunen showed (implicitly) that after adding as many Cohen reals as you wish the ordinal $\omega_2+1$ is not a continuous image of $\omega^*$, hence its clopen algebra does not embed into  $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/\mathrm{fin}$.

Comment: It might be nice to have a definitive summary account of the universality of $P(\omega)/\text{fin}$ posted as an answer.

Comment: @AndreasBlass thanks for your comment! I suspect it is not known whether the statement "${\frak c}$ cannot be embedded in ${\cal P}(\omega)/\text{(fin)}$" implies ${\sf (CH)}$?

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen: I think my answer to this question of yours answers this one as well: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441234/can-the-cardinal-2-aleph-0-be-order-embedded-in-cal-p-omega-textfi?rq=1

Comment: @An elaboration of Noah Schweber's comment: By a classical 1963 theorem of Parovicenko every Boolean algebra of cardinality $\aleph_1$ can be embedded into P(ω) mod FIN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an attempt at a 'definitive summary'.

To begin with positive results: $\mathsf{CH}$ implies a “yes” answer to
this question. The fastest way to see this is to first embed a given partial
order $(P,\le)$ (of cardinality at most $\mathfrak{c}$) into its power set
via $p\mapsto\{x:x\le p\}$ and then take the Boolean subalgebra generated by
the image under this embedding.
An application of Parovichenko's theorem that every Boolean algebra of
cardinality at most $\aleph_1$ embeds into $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/\mathit{fin}$
finishes the argument.

To elaborate a bit on Will Brian's [answer to this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441234): Laver's proof
of the consistency with $\neg\mathsf{CH}$ with the statement that was
published in
[*Linear orders in $(\omega)^\omega$ under eventual dominance*](https://zbmath.org/0464.03046),  in
*Logic colloquium ’78*.

The proof and the proof of the generalization to Boolean algebras that Will
mentioned both proceed by embedding a $\mathfrak{c}$-saturated
linear order or Boolean algebra of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$ respectively into
$\mathcal{P}(\omega)/\mathit{fin}$.
The saturated order/algebra contains all orders/algebras of cardinality at most
$\mathfrak{c}$.
This establishes the consistency of a ``yes'' answer with $\neg\mathsf{CH}$.

It is easy to see that every separable compact space is a continuous image
of $\beta\omega\setminus\omega$ so that, dually, every $\sigma$-centered
Boolean algebra embeds into $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/\mathit{fin}$.

There are many consistent counterexamples: Kunen's result that establishes
that in the Cohen model (with any allowable value of $2^{\aleph_0}$) the
ordinal $\omega_2$ is not embeddable into $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/\mathit{fin}$
shows that Parovichenko's result is sharp.
It also shows that the result on $\sigma$-centered Boolean algebras does not
generalize to partial orders: a linear order is ($\sigma$-)centered.

Other negative results:

1. The Open Colouring Axiom implies that the [*Measure Algebra does not embed
   into $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/\mathit{fin}$*](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm163/fm16325.pdf)
   and, in fact, that many 'natural candidates' are
   [*not continuous images of $\beta\omega\setminus\omega$*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02775024) and so, dually,
   many 'natural candidates' cannot be embedded
   into $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/\mathit{fin}$.
2. It is even consistent that [*there is
   no universal Boolean algebra of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-00-02601-5).
   The proof is topological and yields,
   given a compact space of weight $\mathfrak{c}$, a linearly ordered compact
   space that is not a continuous image of the given space; it dualizes to yield
   given a Boolean algebra of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$ a linearly ordered set
   that cannot be embedded into the given Boolean algebra.